# How do I center the button "Education Oppurtunities" in this container?

Tags: html

// I need the button "Education Opportunities centered. Every time I try it centers everything after this

```
<div class="homebuyers-col-area">
          <div class="homebuyers-col">
         <div class="buyers-cont">
          <h3>
            <a class="no-style" href="/Education">Education</a>
           </h3>
           <p>
            Remain up to date and on top of trends with ASHI's education offerings. The ASHI 
            Online Learning Center hosts a deep library of courses instructed by industry 
            leaders.
          </p>
          </div>
        <a class="home-btn" href="/Education">Education Opportunities</a> Need this to be 
          centered
        </div>
          <div class="homebuyers-col">
          <div class="buyers-cont">
            <h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below CSS:-

```
.home-btn {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pure HTML then you have to use the tag  **tag**.
After adding this you will be able to align the elements in the center tag to be centered.

```
<center>
   //Code Body
</center>
```

And If Modified your code would work fine in this case.

```
<div class="homebuyers-col-area">
      <div class="homebuyers-col">
     <div class="buyers-cont">
      <h3>
        <a class="no-style" href="/Education">Education</a>
       </h3>
       <p>
        Remain up to date and on top of trends with ASHI's education offerings. The ASHI 
        Online Learning Center hosts a deep library of courses instructed by industry 
        leaders.
      </p>
      </div>
      <center>
    <a class="home-btn" href="/Education">Education Opportunities</a> Need this to be 
      centered
      </center>
    </div>
      <div class="homebuyers-col">
      <div class="buyers-cont">
        <h3>
```

And if you are using CSS then simply use padding or text-align: center, tag.

Comment: the `<center>` tag is not supported in HTML5.